# Twitter Follow a page Query

Tags: android, twitter4j, twitter-follow

I want to know that how to follow a page on Twitter using android application??

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Friendship in twitter](http://twitter4j.org/ja/javadoc/twitter4j/api/FriendshipMethods.html#createFriendship%28long%29)

A very simple demo of the function is given [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-hackathon-in-fukuoka/source/browse/trunk/sodefuri/src/jp/jagfukuoka/sodefuri/TimeLineActivity.java?spec=svn167&r=167)